# How to import bookmarks into Opera browser's bookmarks bar?

Tags: bookmarks, opera, import

How to import bookmarks (stored in a HTML file) into Opera browser's **bookmarks bar**?

Following

http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2008/06/12/import-firefox-bookmarks-into-opera-95/

I can only import bookmarks to a subfolder of the bookmarks folder, NOT the bookmarks bar.

Comment: [This article](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Exporting%20bookmarks%20to%20Opera) from Firefox's support team should help you.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is:

1. Click Bookmarks → Manage bookmarks
2. Locate your Firefox bookmarks (hopefully you have them in folders or this could be a long process)
3. Right-click on each folder and select "Show on bookmarks bar"

That's it, you're done. The nice thing is, it alphabetises the contents of each folder for you.