# How to import bookmarks from Firefox into Opera 20 in Windows?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, opera

[This old question](https://superuser.com/q/249014/162573) is too outdated to be of any significance - it involves the old version of Opera, and the browser is now very different. So please don't flag this as duplicate.

---

Opera 20 has a bookmarks bar which can contain also folders. But I don't seem to find a convenient way of importing my bookmarks from Firefox while keeping all their structure.

I've discovered that drag and drop works for individual links but not for folders and that is useless for hundreds of bookmarks.

Comment: [I have done it this way:](http://superuser.com/a/726383/50173) Export Firefox bookmarks as HTML » import into Chrome Portable » copy Chrome's `bookmarks` file to Opera 20

Comment: @nixda - why is it important to use a portable Chrome and not Google Chrome? I use a portable Chromium and the profile folders are (like GC's) in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local

Comment: In your case, It's not important. But your question doesn't say that you have Chrome. So I recommended a way without installing additional software. Others may find it useful with a portable Chrome version

Comment: @nixda - the solution sounds natural. i will try to use it but for the moment my ff bookmarks are but very partially imported in chrome, i'll see and comment

Answer (score 2):

### Simple way to import your bookmarks/favorites to Opera

1. Click on the Opera Tab/Button/Menu key in the top lefthand corner. (button has half of red O followed by Opera spelled out)
2. Scroll down until you come across "Get Extensions", click Get Extensions.( You will then be routed to a page that say Opera add-ons in left corner of screen) ( the page looks like an app store)
3. Locate the search tool in the website, not from the tool bars of the browser. The search box is loacated on the right side of the screen below the Red "Opera Software" bar.( Search for addons will be greyed out inside of search box with magnifying glass icon next to it)
4. Type bookmarks in search menu and press enter or click magnifying glass inside search box.
5. Select "Bookmarks Manager" Addon/App. (It is in the shape of a red bookmarker with 4 horizontal white lines inside of it.)
6. You should be on the page with "Bookmarks Manager" System info and reviews. Once here click on the green rectangular bar with white words that read "Add to Opera" or the white plus sign to the left of "Add to Opera".
7. It will then install and you will be routed to the Bookmark Manager add on page. There will also be a shortcut for Bookmark Manager to the right of the search/address bar once installed (a grey bookmarker with horizontal white lines).
8. Select the drop down arrow to the right of import bookmarks or click the bold words "Import bookmarks"
9. Follow the on screen prompts/directions under import bookmarks, upload favorites, and you're done!
10. Enjoy (on any page you want to bookmark you can right click or click the short cut)